# Setting default microphone input

Tags: macos, mac, headphones, microphone, airpods

I would like to set a default input to be always the internal microphone. Sometimes when I connect my AirPods to the MacBook the input changes to the AirPods' microphones which results in much worse audio quality. The same thing happens with my second pair of BT headphones.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make airpods microphones disabled by default when pairing with a mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340779/make-airpods-microphones-disabled-by-default-when-pairing-with-a-mac)